# Potential Squeeze Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that, if {$x_n$}, {$y_n$}, and {$z_n$} are sequences such that $y_n = x_{2n}$ and $z_n = x_{2n-1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $y_n \rightarrow a$ and $z_n \rightarrow a$, then $x_n \rightarrow a$.

My gut says squeeze theorem, but I cannot seem to demonstrate that one sequence is greater and one is less than?

Perhaps this is not the approach, is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that all terms get near $a$ as $a \to \infty$, both those with even index and with odd index.

Comment: @coffeemath. You probably meant to say: as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: is this logic enough for a formal proof?

Comment: Squeeze theorem might make sense when you have a "termwise" ordering of the sequences, this is, something of the form $a_n\leq b_n\leq c_n$. If $a_n$ and $c_n$ converge to $a$ then $b_n$ would too. With the hypothesis you specified, you can't deduce any such ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @coffeemath's suggestion. Fix $\varepsilon>0$, since $\{y_n\}$ and $\{z_n\}$ converge to $a$ you know there are $N_y$ and $N_z$ st $|y_{n}-a|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N_y$ and $|z_{n}-a|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N_z$.

Now, since

$$x_n=\begin{cases}y_k&& \text{if }n=2k\\
z_k&&\text{if }n=2k-1\end{cases}$$

Then let $N_x=2\max\{N_y,N_z\}$. This would imply $|x_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N_x$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach. By contradiction.

Assume $\{x_n\}\not\rightarrow a$. Therefore there is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ that does not converge to $a$. This subsequence must contain an infinite number of even (or odd) indexed terms from $\{x_n\}$ and would therefore contain a subsequence of $\{y_n\}$ (or $\{z_n\}$). This would imply that $\{y_n\}$ (or $\{z_n\}$) does not converge to $a$, a contradiction.

Thanks to @N.S. for pointing out an error in the first version.

Comment: The part "would therefore be a subsequence" it is actually incorrect. What you probably mean is "would therefore contain a subsequence"

Comment: Well, if all the terms in such subsequence are even indexed terms, say $\{x_{2k_i}\}$, then it is a subsequence of $\{y_n\}$, namely $\{y_{k_i}\}$. Similarly if all the terms are odd indexed. I think I do mean "be a subsequence", don't you think?

Comment: $x_{3n}$ contains infinitely odd and even indexed terms but is neither a subsequence of $x_{2n}$ nor a subsequence of $x_{2n+1}$..... More exactly, what if some indexes are odd and some are even?

Comment: That is true, I'll fix the answer. Thanks for pointing that out!